# Custom filter drop wizard with database information

Tags: database, filter, dropwizard

I'm using dropwizard 0.7.0 and I would like to create a custom filter.

The custom filter should check if a token exists in the database.
What is the correct way to create the filter and register this filter in the Application class?

I used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166603/custom-jetty-filters-in-dropwizard) to implement the filter, this is working but when I change the code to this:

```
final AuthenticationDAO authenticationDAO = new AuthenticationDAO(hibernateBundle.getSessionFactory());
environment.servlets().addFilter("authenticationFilter", new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationDAO)).addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), false, "/transaction/*");
```

This is my filter:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

    private final AuthenticationDAO authenticationDAO;

    public AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationDAO authenticationDAO) {
        this.authenticationDAO = authenticationDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String authenticationToken = ((Request) servletRequest).getHeader(Constants.HEADER_TOKEN_PARAM_NAME);

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)servletResponse;

        if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(authenticationToken)){
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        } else if(!authenticationDAO.findByAuthenticationToken(authenticationToken).isPresent()){
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

When the filter will be accessed, I get the error below because there is no session active:

WARN  [2014-04-22 14:37:42,733] org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler: /test/show
! org.hibernate.HibernateException: No session currently bound to execution context
! at org.hibernate.context.internal.ManagedSessionContext.currentSession(ManagedSessionContext.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
! at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1013) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]

Answer (score 10):

To enable the DropWizard "magic" (Hibernate) in non-managed parts of your code, you'll have to inject a SessionFactory. You can see how to create one in the DropWizard configuration:

https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/hibernate.html

Then you can inject that sessionFacotry into your AuthenticationFilter in the constructor.

In the filter you'll have to manually bind the hibernate session, like:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String authenticationToken = ((Request) servletRequest).getHeader(Constants.HEADER_TOKEN_PARAM_NAME);

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.setDefaultReadOnly(true);
        session.setCacheMode(CacheMode.NORMAL);
        session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
        ManagedSessionContext.bind(session);
        // DropWizard magic enabled from this point.

    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)servletResponse;

    if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(authenticationToken)){
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    } else if(!authenticationDAO.findByAuthenticationToken(authenticationToken).isPresent()){
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
    } else {
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

        session.close();
        // DropWizard magic disabled from this point.


}
```

This is the essense. Anything happening between the bind() and close() will have DropWizard magic enabled - also in the managed Dao's. You could refine it by making it more robust with error handling etc.

This works even if you are hitting a managed resource like the one in your example. What happens is that the DropWizards RequestDispatcher activates and do the same thing, you do: it opens a session and bind it to the thread. The effect is that the managed resource uses another session than the one you opened manually AND that the one you originally bound is removed without cleanup. The effect of THIS in your example is that the magic has ended after the call to doFilter(...). If you want to access the database hereafter, you'll have to rebind the session you created before. Just call:

```
        ManagedSessionContext.bind(session);
```

I haven't experienced any problems with the technique, but one place I could imagine issues would be if you need to access data in one session made in another session. This could require some tweaking with isolation levels.

Comment: I've used this as well to solve the same problem when creating a dropwizard task.

Answer (score 1):

I'm hitting this myself and I think my problem is as discussed in the Dropwizard thread:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/dropwizard-user/LE6FYIpSDQ0/X5smCEZWltcJ

In brief, you may need to open and bind your own session - my classes that are managed by Dropwizard are using sessions just fine, but the classes that aren't managed by dropwizard hit this error.

I'm trying to decide between opening and binding my own sessions, and just moving the class to one managed by Dropwizard so that I can use the @UnitOfWork annotation.

Adding to this - if you aren't in a @UnitOfWork (which appears to only be valid on the rest calls) then you can use a session just fine - but you can't use the DAO layer. If you use a DAO, you'll get that error. There may be more to this, but for my purposes I just used a SQLQuery:

```
        SQLQuery deleteQuery = session.createSQLQuery("DELETE FROM MYTABLE WHERE REPORTTIME < ?");
        deleteQuery.setTimestamp(0, cutoffDate.toDate());
        deleteQuery.executeUpdate();
```

Whether that's the best solution is debatable, but for my purposes it was quite sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your can try:

```
import com.google.common.base.Strings;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter;

import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    private final AuthenticationDAO authenticationDAO;

    public AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationDAO authenticationDAO) {
        this.authenticationDAO = authenticationDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(final ContainerRequest containerRequest) {
        String authenticationToken = containerRequest.getHeaderValue(Constants.HEADER_TOKEN_PARAM_NAME);

        if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(authenticationToken)) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
        } else if (!authenticationDAO.findByAuthenticationToken(authenticationToken).isPresent()) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).build());
        }
        return containerRequest;
    }
}
```

and in the run-method you can add:

```
environment.jersey().getResourceConfig().getContainerRequestFilters().add(new AuthenticationFilter(...));
```

This pull request, https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/pull/541, might cover your needs.

Comment: thanks for your answer but this is not the correct answer, I should add an url pattern. The filter won't be accessed, with this solution.

Comment: This is also giving an error when accessing the check for the token:
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No session currently bound to execution context

Comment: How to add url pattern in this way?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the correct way, but you can't get the url from containerRequest-object and do someting like:
        final Pattern urlPattern = Pattern.compile("url regex pattern");
        if(urlPattern.matcher(containerRequest.getAbsolutePath().getPath()).matches()) {
            return containerRequest;
        }

Comment: I don't use Hibernate so I'm sure what causes this problem. Check that username and passwords are valid. :) Is it only when using the filter you have problem with Hibernate? If no, try to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises when using AuthenticationDAO outside a transaction. As described in the [DropWizard manual](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/manual/hibernate.html#transactional-resource-methods), the annotation [@UnitOfWork](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/dropwizard-hibernate/apidocs/io/dropwizard/hibernate/UnitOfWork.html) can be used to create a transactional boundary.

However to make this work for classes other than Jersey Resources, you'll need to use the [UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/dropwizard-hibernate/apidocs/io/dropwizard/hibernate/UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory.html).

First create a factory.

```
UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory proxyFactory = new UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory("session factory", hibernateBundle.getSessionFactory());
```

Then use it for creating the AuthenticationFilter.

```
AuthenticationFilter filter = proxyFactory.create(AuthenticationFilter.class, AuthenticationDAO.class, authenticationDAO);
environment.servlets().addFilter("authenticationFilter", filter).addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), false, "/transaction/*");
```

Finally annotate doFilter with @UnitOfWork.

```
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {
    @UnitOfWork
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        ...
```